# The provider need a dynamic token after login yodlee

Tags: yodlee

I am working on Yoodle and I am logging into a provider which needs a dynamic token after the login in. When I fill out the form, my provider redirects to another page giving me a number to encrypter in a electronic device.  The electronic device is a safenet.

I am trying to follow these [instructions](https://developer.yodlee.com/API_Resources/Integration_Guide#LinkingAccountsUsingAPIs).

I don't know if I need to invoke again the POST `/providers/providerAccount` or invoke PUT `/providers/providerAccount`

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass the provider's login form with valid credentials to POST `/{cobrandName}/v1/providerAccounts` (Add Account API).
2. You have to poll GET `/{cobrandName}/v1/providerAccounts/{providerAccountId}` (Get Provider Account Details API) until you get MFA form.
3. Pass the MFA form with valid values to PUT `/{cobrandName}/v1/providerAccounts` (Update Account API)
4. Finally poll GET `/{cobrandName}/v1/providerAccounts/{providerAccountId}` (Get Provider Account Details API) to get final account addition status.